# How do you make two conditions work as one in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose there is a database:

| Id | Name | course | faculty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ben | 1 | s |
| 2 | Ben | 1 | t |
| 3 | Ben | 2 | s |
| 4 | Tom | 1 | s |

And I want to make such a query: The name is Ben and he is not studying in the 1st course of the faculty of s.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Name = "Ben" AND course <> 1 AND faculty <> "s"
```

I know that this query is incorrect, but I can not figure out how to write this query correctly? I want to get in result rows with Id 2 and 3.

Comment: Incorrect - in which way? not the desired result, or raising an error?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Double quotes are usually for identifiers, and single quotes for literals.)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Name = "Ben" AND Not (course =1 AND faculty = "s")
```

Answer (score 2):

> The name is Ben and he is not studying in the 1st course of the faculty of s.

If I understand your task right, then this should work:

```
...WHERE Name = "Ben" AND NOT (course = 1 AND faculty = "s");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an other solution using the logical `OR` operator to connect two or more conditions :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE Name = 'Ben' 
      AND ( course <> 1 OR faculty <> 's' )
```

Comment: de Morgan's law, they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Say exactly as you meant it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Name = "Ben" AND NOT (course =1 AND faculty ='s')
```

See also [Boolean algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) or similar descriptions of logical ops.